# Fuzzy Logic Lookup - How to use calculated columns

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012, fuzzy-search, fuzzy-logic

We're starting to implement Unicode as we've added some international customers. There are some issues comparing character data in SSIS because of capitals, accents, and other data problems.
I've thought that the `Fuzzy logic lookup` could be a good solution. However, when testing this solution out, I realized that in a lot of our existing code we limit what data to process, and send in those values by parameters.
I've noticed that in the `Fuzzy Lookup`, I can specify the name of the table, but I can't make changes like remove a `%` from a field and turn it into a decimal. Any ideas how we can setup the lookup with calculated fields?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create a view in your database with the proper transformation your require using a sql query.